# PSQL.exe can not type any cod, closing when pressing Enter

Tags: windows, database, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 10, and I wanted to install sample database by PSQL, but It's not typing any thing. mean empty screen, whatever I'm typing, what's the solution, please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SU.  Please could you expand on your question, perhaps include a screenshot so we can see what you are doing?  Use [edit] to add new info.

Comment: screenshot will not be useful, cause , it's empty (Black) because i can't do anything. No action happening when I'm trying to write a code

Comment: If your screenshot is black regardless of what you do, then you aren't in a command environment.  There is always a prompt.  So you aren't running something that can accept commands. If you aren't able to provide any more information then it is doubtful you'll be able to receive help here.  I strongly recommend you [edit] your question and provide as much information as you can or it will likely be closed as unclear.